# Remove bottom right button from google maps flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

There is a button in the bottom right of the google maps API google maps widget. I never added this button myself. How do I remove it?

[image: Bottom Right button]

edit:
here is my code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("TravelBuddy"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          GoogleMap(
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            initialCameraPosition: 
              CameraPosition(
              target: _center,
              zoom: 11.0,
              ),
            mapType: _currentMapType,
            markers: _markers,
            onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child:  Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  button(_onMapTypeButtonPressed, Icons.map),
                  SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  button(_onAddMarkerButtonPressed, Icons.add_location),
                  SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  button(_goToPosition1, Icons.location_searching),
     ],),),),],),);}
```

Comment: Which google maps plugin are you using? Canc you post your code base too?

Comment: If anyone want to remove zoom control. Add `zoomControlsEnabled: false` to google map view.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thanks for the code.

Try putting an option "my LocationButtonEnabled" in GoogleMap() widget

```
     GoogleMap(
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            initialCameraPosition: 
              CameraPosition(
              target: _center,
              zoom: 11.0,
              ),
            mapType: _currentMapType,
            markers: _markers,
            onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
            myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
            options: GoogleMapOptions(
              myLocationEnabled:true
              //there is a lot more options you can add here
            )
          ),
```

Comment: What if I would like the user's position to be shown?

Comment: Then you can dynamically hide/show that button by listening to the movement of the camera. Create a boolean, if it moves, u set the state to false, else true. Or you can create your own button elsewhere

Comment: Even if I add this option it does not hide.

Comment: @joshLor try putting that option inside GoogleMap() instead. I think they have that parameter.

Comment: @joshLor there's a myLocationButtonEnabled option, i edited my answer

Comment: yes, I added 'myLocationEnabled: false' yet it still doesn't work

Comment: It works now, I just had to restart the emulator instead of hot reload.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. Adding 'zoomControlsEnabled: false,' in the GoogleMap() widget worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `myLocationButtonEnabled: false` in GoogleMap Widget.